# Как изменить размер SKTexture?

Tags: ios, swift, spritekit

У меня есть анимация (код ниже) как увеличить её??
(SKTexture не принимает CGSize - там есть только метод возвращающий его .size())

```
var enemyAnimationTextures:[SKTexture] = []
    let action = SKAction.animate(with: enemyAnimationTextures, timePerFrame: 0.1)

    enumNodeDelete.run(SKAction.sequence([action, SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SKTexture это просто картинка, которая накладывается на SKSpriteNode. Вам нужно менять размер самой ноды. Документация - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktexture.

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже решил это просто сделав анимацию в 2 раза больше